# javascript regular expression validator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box named id. I need to form a text box validator where I want the id number in the text box to be of the format  a letter, followed by 3 numbers (each in range 0-8), a separator "+" or "-", and another 4 numbers (each 0-9).
Can anyone tell me how I could write this regular expression validator in javascript...
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here is a great resource, this is a link to an online RegEx Utility http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx  ALSO http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php

Comment: Homework? For reference you could try http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they pointed out above, this would be a great exercise to learn how to do regexes yourself. However, in the interest of being helpful, here is the regex you need:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][0-8]{3}[-+][0-9]{4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you're looking for (assuming by "letter" you mean "latin lower- or upper-case letter") is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][0-8]{3}[+-][0-9]{4}$/
```